# DS18B20 waterproof temp sensor arduino code error

Tags: arduino

i have been trying to get a DS18B20 waterproof temperature sensor to work with my arduino. this is the code i am using:

```
#include <OneWire.h>

int SensorPin = 2; 


OneWire ds(SensorPin); 

void setup(void) {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {
float temp = getTemp();
Serial.println(temp);

delay(100); 

}


float getTemp(){


byte data[12];
byte addr[8];

if ( !ds.search(addr)) {
//no more sensors on chain, reset search
ds.reset_search();
return -1000;
}

if ( OneWire::crc8( addr, 7) != addr[7]) {
Serial.println("CRC is not valid!");
return -1000;
}

if ( addr[0] != 0x10 && addr[0] != 0x28) {
Serial.print("Device is not recognized");
return -1000;
}

ds.reset();
ds.select(addr);
ds.write(0x44,1); 

byte present = ds.reset();
ds.select(addr); 
ds.write(0xBE); 


for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
data[i] = ds.read();
}

ds.reset_search();

byte MSB = data[1];
byte LSB = data[0];

float TRead = ((MSB 8) | LSB); 
float Temperature = TRead / 16;

return Temperature;

}
```

i keep getting the following errors:

In funtion 'float gerTemp()':
error: expected ')' before numeric constant
error: expected ')' before ';' token

i cant figure out what these mean or how to fix it. can someone help me? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you take a look at the lines with the error:

```
float TRead = ((MSB 8) | LSB);
```

You can see    `MSB 8`   - there is no operator between these arguments. According to the context, it should be:

```
float TRead = ((MSB << 8) | LSB);
```

Maybe even (just to be sure):

```
float TRead = (((uint16_t)MSB << 8) | LSB);
```

Comment: thanks! it worked, and the errors aren't popping up anymore, but I'm not sure how to read the temperature. there isn't anything with temperature readings showing up. maybe that part of the code is missing? could someone tell me what that part of the code would be? i cant figure it out. Thanks!